# How to write else for this script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, responsive-design

I am coding for this website and
I need to change javascript between two scripts for pc-view and mobile-view.
I found this code online and it does load specific script on mobile view but I would like to switch to another one when viewing in PC.

Therefore, I need to know how to write "else" part of the following script so that I can load "pc" version.

```
<!--
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > 0) {
//what u want to run in mobile devices 
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.src = "js/script_photo_sp.js";//file directory
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);}
alert(s.src);//for running test purposes
//-->
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Honestly the easiest thing to do here would be to use an if statement and test against a CSS value which changes at different media queries. For example if you had a div which was display:none at mobile and display:block at desktop. test to see if that div is display: none - if true run mobile function, if false (else) run desktop function. Obviously this div could be any element class or ID. The problems with using useragents or even screen sizes is that these can be inconsistent. Basing responsive JS off the CSS ensures they fire at the same time. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also - my problem with the below answers is that they allow for inconsistency, for example their code would not work on Windows phones.

Comment: @Callum - all good points - but the question isn't about how to build robust device detection..

Comment: @Stumblor No but the question was about how to change between scripts, I just feel like using a CSS property is a much neater solution overall, since the example code wouldn't work on all mobile devices ^^

Comment: If that was the case, he would be much better off detecting browser functionality inline, rather than swapping out scripts. `Modenizer` would be a better tool for this purpose.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500868/how-to-detect-the-browser-capabilities

Comment: Thanks @Callum I am not quite sure what you meant by "windows phone". Are you talking about windows based mobile phones that we used to see around the market? I'm quite sure there are still some users who uses those phones but my client is not worried about windows phone and as long as this works for most of iPhone and Android devices, I am good to go with just switching between scripts! Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Hi @HirohitoYamada I was indeed referring to windows based O/S mobiles (mainly the nokia lumia series now), if this isn't a concern then no problem ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') > 0 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') > 0) {
        //what u want to run in mobile devices 
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.type = "text/javascript";
          s.src = "js/script_photo_sp.js";//file directory
          document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    } else {
      // code for pc here
    }
    alert(s.src);//for running test purposes
```

Comment: Thanks @Lunokhod! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Look for the curly braces, in this case, at the end of this line

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);} // end of condition
else {
   // else code goes here
}
```

Comment: thank you for educational answer! I will look into this later on!